# Json Passing in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

i pass Json String from my WebService to My code Using NSDictionary

```
-(void)getData :(NSData*)respo{
NSError *error;
NSMutableDictionary *jons =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:respo options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSMutableArray *rnameary = [jons  objectForKey:@"posts"];
NSMutableArray *tempary =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0;i < [rnameary count];i++) {
    CfResultFatch *rs = [[CfResultFatch alloc] initWithName:[[rnameary objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"BrandName"]
                                                       cipd:[[rnameary objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Dose"]]; 
   [tempary addObject:rs];                             
}
result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:tempary];
[temptab reloadData];
}
```

using this i get Data from WebServies, Data like

```
{
    ActiveCrNo = "";
    BPL = 0;
    BloodGroupIDF = 1;
    CRNumber = 0000187;
    CashlessDetail = fgfghgfh;
    CastIDF = 19;
    ClassIDF = 7;
    CloseCrNo = 0;
    CompanyNo = "";
    DateOfBirth =         {
        date = "1987-08-20 00:00:00";
        timezone = "Europe/Berlin";
        "timezone_type" = 3;
    };
    Disability = 0;
    EntryDate =         {
        date = "2011-08-20 16:30:00";
        timezone = "Europe/Berlin";
        "timezone_type" = 3;
    };
    ExpiredDate = "<null>";
    ExtraField1 = 0;
    ExtraField2 = "<null>";
    FName = "Mrs.Shatayu";
    Gender = 0;
    HospitalIDF = 4;
    IncomeGroupIDF = "<null>";
    IsExpired = 0;
    IsNewPatient = 0;
    LName = Sharma;
    MName = Maheshbhai;
    MaritalStatus = 0;
    PAN = "";
    PatientIDP = 202;
    QualificationIDF = "<null>";
    ReligionIDF = "<null>";
    Remarks = "";
    SkillSetIDF = "<null>";
    UIDNumber = "";
},
```

And so on around 500 block like one is here.
i easily getField Like FNAME, LNAME, in sort outer field i Access easily but problem to get "DateOfBirth" field i was try all the things but nothing work if some one know it then give me suggestion

Comment: what problem u r facing?

Comment: DateOfBirth give me return 3 field, i want to Access only date then how i Store it ? like i stored FNAME on Other field

Comment: it is give me set of 3 Filed and if i put in objectForKey field then it is going to error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateOfBirth field is just an NSDictionary. So you could retrieve it like:

```
...
NSDictionary *dof = [[rnameary objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"DateOfBirth"];
NSString *date = [dof objectForKey:@"date"];
...
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run a loop for accessing value for different keys in this NSDictionary, again assign the `objectForKey: DateOfBirth` to another NSDictionary. Like:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self getData:response];

NSDictionary *dictDateofBirth = [dict objectForKey:@"DateOfBirth"];
```

Now you can use this as an individual NSDictionary and access the date if birth like:

```
NSString *dob = [dictDateofBirth objectForKey:@"date"];
```

Comment: i will try it but it going to cresh