# parse JSON .  I have server response

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Json Passing in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783801/json-passing-in-iphone)

i am new in JSON Parsing . i have a server response how i can fetch the "Device Name and Id" of 0 index.

thanks in Advance

```
{

    Successfully =   

  (

                {

            0 =             {

              DeviceName = Tommy;

                DeviceTypeId = 1;

                EMEI = xxxxxx;

                GId = xxxxx;

                Id = 105;

                Pet = "<null>";

                PetImage = "352022008228784.jpg";

                ProtocolId = xxxx;

                SimNo = xxxxx;
            };

        }
    );
}
```

Comment: What are we looking at? Is this some plain string or data received or is this already sort of parsed?

Comment: Apparently this is from an NSLog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *myJsonResponse; // Let's assume that this is the response you provided

NSString *deviceName = [[[myJsonResponse valueForKey:@"Successfully"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKeyPath:@"0.DeviceName"];

id theId = [[[myJsonResponse valueForKey:@"Successfully"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKeyPath:@"0.Id"]; // I am using "id" type here since I don't know if this is an NSString or an NSNumber
```

Comment: thanks you are right i forget "Successfully". thanks again

Comment: i have more then one index but when i use....
    NSDictionary* menu = [parsedJSON objectForKey:@"Successfully"]; NSLog(@"value of count is %d",[menu count]);..... it prints 1. but i wants output 2. according to server Response

Comment: Yes that's normal. Inside "Successfully" array you have only one object (a dictionary), having multiple key/values. Try this: `NSDictionary* menu = [[parsedJSON objectForKey:@"Successfully"] objectAtIndex:0];` and then count the menu object.

Answer (score 0):

Use a NSDictionary and the method valueForKey.

Comment: i use this but . out put is null......   NSDictionary* menu = [parsedJSON objectForKey:@"0"];  
    
    NSLog(@"VALUE OF PARSED JASON 0th index %@",[parsedJSON objectForKey:@"0"]);
    NSLog(@"VALUE OF MENU IS %@",menu);

Comment: @GauravBOSS you're forgetting the "Successfully" array, which is also a key in your dictionary. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the complete JSON response, you'll want to create a dictionary from that 0 index which should look something like

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [JSON objectForKey:@"0"];
```

Where JSON is the name of the object that this is stored in.  Then you should be able to access everything within by just getting the object for key that you want i.e.

```
NSString *deviceName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"DeviceName"];
```

None of this was tested and was just done from memory so take that with a grain of salt.